# For what value of parameter m is there no solution for the equation $-x^2+(m-3)\vert x\vert=0,25(m^2-1)$?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

$-x^2+(m-3)\vert x\vert=0,25(m^2-1)\\t^2-\left(m-3\right)t+0,25\left(m^2-1\right)=0$

$\triangle_t=-6m+10$

$\triangle_t<0\iff x>\frac53$

Why the correct answer is $m\in\left(-\infty,\;-1\right)\cup\left(1,\;+\infty\right)$ ?

Comment: Is there a system of equation  ? (your question is not clear )

Answer (score 1):

The equation $x^2 - (m-3) x + 0.25 (m^2-1) = 0$ does have solutions for $m > 5/3$, but if $m < 1$ those solutions are both negative, so they are not solutions of $x^2 - (m-3) |x| + 0.25 (m^2-1) = 0$.  Note that $x=0$ is a solution for $m = 1$.

Your "correct answer" is not quite correct. The actual correct answer is $m \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [1,\infty)$, because $m=\pm 1$ are allowed.